# Interpretation: Mediation with a squared regression model (U-shape)

Tags: regression, interpretation, mediation, quadratic-form

I did a mediation analysis with Person-Organization Fit as IV, Organizational Attraction as Mediator and Organizational Choice Intention as DV. As the regression assumption 'Linearity in the parameters' was violated, I had to include Fit squared **in addition** to the IV Fit in the analysis. Unfortunately, I got results for the effects, that differ in significance:
For the IV Fit, the total effect and the direct effect are not significant whereas the indirect is significant. For the IV Fit squared, the total effect is significant but the indirect and direct effect are not significant. It would be great if someone could give me advice how to interpret these results.

Comment: Is there nobody who can help my in this issue?